# WordPress sire not always rendering page correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress site with a template. Sometimes when the page loads fine, but sometimes the formatting is wrong.

- Everything aligns to the left.
- All links are underlined (when they shouldn't be in the theme).
- Other aspects are off.

Here's the navbar when the page is working as intended:

[image]

Here's the navbar when it isn't working:

[image]

[I used my browser's `view page source` options get get the html of the page so I could diff it.](https://www.diffchecker.com/yJzfgPsa)

Comment: Looks like something conflicting with CSS could you check and make sure that the original style sheet is not being overrided by something else possibly?

Comment: Most probably your net was down or spiking so the browser has an issue retrieving the files (like css, js, etc) from external links. Happens to my sites often too.

Comment: I get this from time to time.  Usually it's a cache issue for me.

Comment: I've had this issue on and for for a few weeks. I'm running on a pretty small AWS instance, could that be the cause?